# Restricted Permutation and Combination (More than 1 zero not allowed)

Tags: permutations, combinations

A zip code contains 3 digits. How many different zip codes can be made with the digits 0,1,2 if below condition applied:

a) More than 1 zero not allowed

b) 3 or more consecutive are not allowed

My verbal solution: Total number possible minus condition 1 minus condition 2. But I cannot figure out a formula for 1st and 2nd condition. Though the total possible number can be calculated as 3*3*3 i.e 27 (if I am not wrong)

Thanks in advance

Comment: brute force seems very resonable, it would have probably taken less than typing the question

Comment: Can you give an example of a code that does not satisfy rule $b)$?

Comment: @JorgeFernández, I am really nieve in mathematics world, so brute force is quite an alien term for me.

Comment: write out the $27$ possibilities and check each one (that would be the brute force aproach)

Comment: ignore the term "more"(it is for the more generic problem) in rule b)
, for the current problem, 111 should not be considered as a valid input. Later we will use the suggested formula/solution for more bigger input

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
 I am looking for a formula so that I can use it for much bigger inputs.

Comment: you are going to need generating functions or some sensible tecnique to deal with recursion in order to get a general formula that deals with $b$ for zip codes of large size

Answer (score 1):

We calculate the codes that satisfy $a)$.

there are $2^3$ that don't contain $1$ and there are $3\times 2^2$ that contain $1$ ($3$ ways to select where the $1$ goes and $2^2$ ways to fill the rest).

From here we must substract the ones that satisfy $a)$ and not $b)$, clearly there are two of them, $222$ and $333$.

Hence the final answer is $2^3+3\times2^2-2=8+12-2=18$

Comment: sorry for presenting the question in a confusing way: I would like to have a result derives as:  (3x3x3) -(a)-(b).  for this case (a) contains the set: [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(2,0,0),(0,0,2),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),] and (b) [(1,1,1)]. so the result sud be 27-7-1 = 19.

Comment: it doesn't work that way, in either case it would be something like $3^3-a)-b)+ab)$, look up inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I didnot pay attention in case of bigger input. The problem I am trying to solve is to write a function somthing simplar. The second function is what I wrote in the post.
f(4,1,3,3)=43
f(3,1,3,3)=19
Where first input to the function is the zip code length and last is the possible digits lenght starting for zero (i.e. 0,1,2). So I have to achive 19 for second example (18 as suggested by you will not work)

Comment: there are only $18$

Comment: I see. last question, probably. what is the way to count, how many digits contain more then 1 zero out of total possible count(27). I mean to calculate (a) seperatly